# Function to store a file line by line gives weird results

Tags: c, io

I have written a function that takes a file and stores each line in an array of strings.

Here are the functions involved:

```
char **get_lines(FILE *file) {
    int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 2048;
    int num_lines = 19;
    char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_lines);

    // Make sure to start at the beginning of the file
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    char *line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    int i = 0; // index counter for lines

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        // Only add to lines if the line is not a single newline character
        if (strcmp(line, "\n")) {

            int len = strlen(line);

            // Remove the last character as
            // it should always be a newline character
            if (len < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
                line[len-1] = '\0';
            }

            lines[i] = malloc(strlen(line));
            lines[i++] = line;
            printf("%s\n", lines[i-1]); // This prints the lines correctly.
        }
    }

    for (int x=0; x < num_lines; x++) {
        // This prints strings containing only a newline character.
        printf("%s", lines[x]); 
    }

    return lines;
}
```

What is so confusing to me is that if I print the line immediately after adding it to the array (within the while loop), the correct string is printed. But if I print each line after `lines` is done being defined (outside the while loop), it prints only strings containing a newline character.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT**
After not modifying the program, now the second printf statement just prints nothing to the console.

If it helps I am using CLion.

Comment: regarding: `if (len < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
                line[len-1] = '\0';
            }`   This would be much better written as: `line[ strspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(line))` the function `strlen()` returns the 'index' to the NUL character, which is 1 short of the number of characters in the string. so the statement should be: `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(line)+1)`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: you might want to look at the POSIX function: `getline()` as that would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: where did the 'magic' number 19 come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is leaking memory as it ignored the *malloc* inside loop, and it was assigning the same address of *line* to *lines[i]*

```
char **get_lines(FILE *file) {
int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 2048;
int num_lines = 19;
char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_lines);

// Make sure to start at the beginning of the file
fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);

char *line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

int i = 0; // index counter for lines

while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
    // Only add to lines if the line is not a single newline character
    if (strcmp(line, "\n")) {

        int len = strlen(line);

        // Remove the last character as
        // it should always be a newline character
        if (len < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
            line[len-1] = '\0';
        }

        lines[i] = malloc(strlen(line));
        strncpy(lines[i], line, len);
        i++;
        printf("%s\n", lines[i-1]); // This prints the lines correctly.
    }
 }

for (int x=0; x < num_lines; x++) {
    // This prints strings containing only a newline character.
    printf("%s", lines[x]); 
}

 return lines;
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue, but the strcpy line results in an "Invalid write of Size 1" according to valgrind.

Comment: Do you know what could fix this?

Comment: Try with strncpy, if it is returning one it means it is of length 1, something could be wrong with pointer or string

Comment: I am using strncpy but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Also, why is it bad to store lines[i] as the same memory address as line? They're both allocated to the heap so they should stay accessible.

Comment: lines[i] can only hold a pointer, and pointer of a line if stored at lines[i] will  contains same value in all locations. Any new value read to line will be reflected in all lines. Please familiarize more on pointer in C.